# Diodes in filter

Tags: diodes, filter, encoder

When I analyzing rotary encoder filtering circuit, I found this filtering mechanism.

[image: Filter circuit]

It uses normal RC filter and then it uses some diode for filtering. This diodes are high speed switching diodes.
I found [diodes datasheet](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/a/bav99_series_nxp.pdf) and I represent that diodes D1 and D2 in schematic above. Those diodes are come with SOT23 package.

My question is how to filter signal using this diodes?Is it reduce noises?

Comment: It's so you don't blow up the gate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diodes are not there for filtering, they're there as 'belt and suspenders' protection in parallel with the internal protection network internal to U1A (which is almost a duplicate, probably with some series resistance).

If a large voltage such as ESD makes its way past the resistor the resulting current will be conducted to ground or to Vdd through one or the other diode.

Another reason to have D1 is if if the power supply suddenly drops in voltage (say a large load or short or partial short), this will discharge C2 through the gate protection network in parallel with the diode, and the diode (most likely, say it's a BAT54 or BAV99) will take the brunt of the current. Otherwise it's conceivable the gate could be directly damaged or latchup could be triggered, causing the gate to be destroyed via power supply current.

You can ignore the diodes in your analysis of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this mechanism in lot of input stages of logic IC before. Now I understood actual function.

Answer (score 2):

It clamps the input voltage to U1A to stay within the supply rails (Or at least not exceed them by much).

It is an input protection component not a filtering one, in that in normal operation it does nothing, but if a fault forces a large voltage onto the input, say ESD/EFT, or just a wiring screwup, it protects the chips input stage by providing a low impedance at the chip input so the excess voltage can be dropped across R2.